# jQuery prepend option to select list

Tags: jquery, html

My select list is for different restaurant types, so the user can select a food type and then click search and they will be returned with a list of their particular food type search.

I have successfully prepended a option to my select drop down by using the following:

```
$("#edit-field-type-value").prepend("<option value=''>Type of Restaurant...</option>").val('');
```

However, if the user selects say, "Chinese" food and hits apply, when the page is refreshed the option in the select list is still my newly prepended "Type of Restaurant...", what I want is for the select to keep their food type in the drop down as the selected option, in this case "Chinese".

My html currently looks like this:

```
<select id="edit-field-type-value" name="field_type_value" class="form-select">
  <option value="">Type of Restaurant...</option>
  <option value="All">- Any -</option>
  <option value="Chinese" selected="selected">Chinese</option>
  <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
  <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="English">English/Traditional</option>
  <option value="American">American</option>
  <option value="Turkish">Turkish</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to store the selected state - either in client(cookie/localstorage) or serverside database etc

Comment: we'll need a little bit more esp the part where yo actually redirect the guy

Comment: Are you using `PHP`or just `Plain HTML` in your form?... because you can easily done that with `$_REQUEST['field_type_value']`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for the response, I'll look in to that.

Comment: @gmo I'm using PHP, drupal to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you are with `Drupal`& `PHP` it's easy to do.
Try with something like:

```
<?PHP
  // First, get the selected value in a $var
  $food_type = $_REQUEST['field_type_value'];
?>
```

Then, you can use a loop for the options or just add to each a condition like:

```
<select id="edit-field-type-value" name="field_type_value" class="form-select">
   ...
   <option value="Chinese" <?PHP if($food_type == 'Chinese')echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Chinese</option>
   ...
</select>
```

---

But... If the options are injected with `jQuery`... you will need to convert that `PHP $var` to `javascript var` like:

```
<?PHP
  $food_type = $_REQUEST['field_type_value'];
  echo '<script>var food_type = "'.$food_type.'";</script>';
?>
```

And then in JS loop...

```
var food_type_loop = ["Type of Restaurant...", "Chinese", "Indian", "more..."]; // all your options

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i=0 ;i<food_type_loop.length; i++) {
            $("#edit-field-type-value").append("<option value='" + food_type_loop[i] + "'>" + food_type_loop[i] + "</option>").val(food_type_loop[i]);
            // reach to the end... now select th proper one
            if(i+1 == food_type_loop.length) select_the_food();
    }
});

function select_the_food(){
    $('#edit-field-type-value option[value="'+food_type+'"]').prop('selected', true);
}
```

#### Fiddle example with jQ http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/hWKkL/1/